# Install elasticsearch 1.1 using brew

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

When I'm installing elasticsearch using `brew` it auto defaults to version `0.90.5`. Is there a way that I can tell brew to install version `1.1`?

Comment: If you run `brew edit elasticsearch`, does it not specify `https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.1.0.tar.gz` as the `url` on line 5 (assuming it opens vim, then literally type `:q` to exit for those unaware)? This should be enough to run `brew install elasticsearch` to get `v1.1.0`.

Comment: All I needed to do was upgrade brew and then run install.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- `brew update` to update your brew
- `brew doctor` optional if you want to check if all good with your system

and then:

- `brew upgrade elasticsearch` to upgrade
- or `brew install elasticsearch`

Finally `brew info elasticsearch` to check your system. My case:

```
$ brew info elasticsearch
elasticsearch: stable 1.1.0, HEAD
http://www.elasticsearch.org
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.0.0 (471 files, 78M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.0.1 (363 files, 79M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.1.0 (31 files, 21M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
==> Caveats
Data:    /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_dionysis_lorentzos/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_dionysis_lorentzos.log
Plugins: /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/

To have launchd start elasticsearch at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load elasticsearch now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

There is a possibility that you run via LaunchAgents the `90.5` That means that on user login ES starts running on the background. So the above should say something like:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
```

I have deleted that file btw.

Then run and check the version & the IP:

```
$ elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
[2014-04-13 17:13:18,006][INFO ][node] [Archie Corrigan] version[1.1.0], pid[8108], build[2181e11/2014-03-25T15:59:51Z]
<<other lines here>>
[2014-04-13 17:13:27,269][INFO ][http ] [Archie Corrigan] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}
```

If you run the above and see that the port is 9201 that means that you run two instances of ES in your mac. The second instance tried to start but the 9200 was already fulfilled so ES tried the next available 9201. You probably need to `unload` the first instance.

When upgrading you need to copy your configuration.

I think that's all you need about ES & brew.

Comment: Just in case someone is cut/pasting commands from this answer be aware that there is a typo on the `brew info` step where elasticsearch is misspelled.

Comment: This answer installs the latest version of elasticsearch, not specifically v1.1

Answer (score 5):

```
$ brew search elasticsearch
```

…then you'll see something like…

```
elasticsearch 
homebrew/versions/elasticsearch17  homebrew/versions/elasticsearch2
```

…then…

```
$  brew install elasticsearch17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew update
brew doctor
```

And than
`brew install elasticsearch`

Or `brew upgrade elasticsearch`